# How to implement a Room LiveData filter

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, android-room, android-livedata

I do not know how to implement a filter query properly inside the Repository and the ViewModel to use it to display the filtered string in a Textview or anything else really. My Entity, Dao, Repository, and ViewModel are as follows:

**User.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_data")
data class User (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String
)
```

**UserDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert
    fun addUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT name FROM user_data WHERE name LIKE :filter LIMIT 1")
    fun getFilteredUser(filter: String): LiveData<String>
}
```

**UserRepository.kt**

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

     fun addUser(user: User) { userDao.addUser(User) }

     fun getFilteredUser(filter: String) {userDao.getFilteredUser(filter)}
}
```

**UserViewModel.kt**

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: UserRepository

    init {
        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
        repository = UserRepository(userDao )    
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun getFilteredUser(filter: String){
        return repository.getFilteredUser(filter)
    }
}
```

How would I proceed from here to make it possible to e.g. display the filtered User String in a textview or anything like that and how do I write the method correctly inside the repository and the viewmodel?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

**UserDao**

change `getFilteredUser` as follows

```
    @Query("SELECT name FROM user_data WHERE name LIKE '%' || :filter || '%' LIMIT 1")
    fun getFilteredUser(filter: String): Stringl̥
```

**UserRepo**

use coroutines to perform the database I/O operations

```
    suspend fun addUser(user: User) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userDao.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getFilteredUser(filter: String): String {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userDao.getFilteredUser(filter)
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    private val _dataToUi = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val dataToUi: LiveData<String>
        get() = _dataToUi

    suspend fun getFilteredUser(filter: String): String? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getFilteredUser(filter)
        }
    }

    // to set the filterquery from the fragment/activity
    fun setFliterQuery(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _dataToUi.value = getFilteredUser(query)
        }
    }
```

**Activity**

```
        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            val queryKey = binding.queryKey.text.toString()
            Log.i("activity", queryKey)
            userViewModel.setFliterQuery(queryKey)
        }

        userViewModel.dataToUi.observe(this) { result ->
            result?.apply {
                Log.i("activity", result)
                binding.resultText.text = result
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I tried it with your solution and I got two problems. First I don't have a fragment class I'm doing everything from the Main Activity, so ```viewLifeCycleOwner``` throws an error. I tried doing ```myViewModel.dataToUi.observe(this, { result -> {result.apply {tv2.text = result}}})``` instead but unfortunately there is a type mismatch between tv2.text which requires a ```Charsequence``` and result which is of type ```Unit```. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: try the answer now

Comment: Using everything like described, nothing changes inside the textview and android studio tells me that the lambda expression is unused.

Comment: @Cion, try the latest code, worked successfully on my device

Comment: This might work unfortunately I never worked before with binding so I have to look into that first, but thank you very much!

Comment: check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) too and if the code is helpful, leave a upvote :)

Comment: Alright I read into it and got it working and your solution works perfectly, a big thanks for your help, time and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I have found :

1 - In your DAO interface, add a parameter for the SQL query you want to use. For example:

```
@Dao
interface CrPairsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM CrPairsModel WHERE columnName = :queryParam")
    fun getCrPairs(queryParam: String): Flow<List<CrPairsModel>>
}
```

In this example, **columnName** represents the column name in the table where you want to apply the query condition, and **queryParam** is the parameter for the query.

2 - Update your repository to pass the parameter value to the DAO method. Here's an example:

```
class CrPairsRepository(private val crPairsDao: CrPairsDao) {
    fun getCrPairsWithQuery(queryParam: String): Flow<List<CrPairsModel>> {
        return crPairsDao.getCrPairs(queryParam)
    }
}
```

In this example, the **getCrPairsWithQuery** function in the repository accepts the **queryParam** parameter and directly calls the DAO's **getCrPairs** method with the parameter value.

3 - Finally, in your ViewModel, update the function that fetches the data to include the parameter value. Here's an example:

```
class CrPairsViewModel(private val crPairsRepository: CrPairsRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _crPairsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<CrPairsModel>>()
    val crPairsLiveData: LiveData<List<CrPairsModel>> = _crPairsLiveData

    fun fetchCrPairsWithQuery(queryParam: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            crPairsRepository.getCrPairsWithQuery(queryParam).collect {
                _crPairsLiveData.value = it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the **fetchCrPairsWithQuery** function in the ViewModel triggers the repository's **getCrPairsWithQuery** function with the provided query parameter. The resulting **Flow** is collected using **collect**, and the emitted value is set to the **crPairsLiveData** using the **_crPairsLiveData.value**.

With these changes, you can now pass a parameter to the SQL query in the DAO method and retrieve the filtered **Flow<List>** in your ViewModel with **crPairsLiveData.observeAsState()** and **.value?.let**