# How to filter a RecyclerView using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I just started to use kotlin and room database, in my fragment i have a `RecyclerView` and an `EditText` which i would use as search for the `RecyclerView`. The RecyclerView's adapter is inside my `ViewModel` observable and i've actually set a TextWatcher to my `EditText` but as the data of the RecyclerView comes from my room DataBase how should i set that filtering?

When the EditText is empty i should return items from the LiveData observable..

Here is my Fragment code:

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var txtSearch: EditText
private val articoliViewModel: ArticoliViewModel
    get() = (activity as MainActivity).articoliViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    txtSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch)

    val adapter = ArticoliListAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    articoliViewModel.articoli.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { articoli ->
        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
        articoli.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
    }

    txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }
    })

}
```

Comment: First decide weather you want to filter current list or you want to filter from the database(If there a pagination involved) . For first u can use  Filterable like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068448/4168607)  . Second option is more straightforward you just have query the DB again with the search String.

Comment: @ADM there is no pagination, and idk what would be better if filter by DB query or by List, i would use something less expansive for the performance

Comment: Then just Use `Filterable` i have added a link above u can find similar answers which make sense to you .

Comment: try a similar approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635201/11034109